# Is there a way to trigger a pop-up notification from Vala MSYS2 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, popup, vala, notify, msys2

I don't like Windows, I just want to check how cross-platform Vala is.

When using `libnoyify` I see

```
    gavr@DESKTOP-B57MHT8 MINGW64 ~
$ ./notify.exe

** (notify.exe:6680): ERROR **: 15:50:47.138: notify.vala:13: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications is unknown
```

in code like that

```
    public static int main (string[] args) {
        string summary = "Short summary";
        string body = "A long description";
        string icon = "dialog-information";

        Notify.init ("My test app");

        try {
            Notify.Notification notification = new Notify.Notification (summary, body, icon);
            notification.show ();
        } catch (Error e) {
            error ("Error

: %s", e.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So is there a way to trigger a pop-up notification from Vala?

All I found is [this](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/) but I do not think it is suitable for Windows 10, it seems it stopped in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what is going on I'll break it down into Vala, GTK+, system notifications and D-Bus.

It looks like you've compiled your program and run it on Windows. So Vala and the C compiler have done their things and produced a binary that runs on Windows. Vala is often used with the GTK+ graphical toolkit and GTK+ uses different [GDK backends](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/platform-support.html) for things like creating windows and handling input. GTK+ also uses different [Cairo backends](https://www.cairographics.org/) for rendering widgets across platforms. GDK and Cairo uses the Windows API on Windows, Quartz API on macOS and so on.

System wide notifications don't appear to be as cross platform as GDK and Cairo. The common standard for Unix is the [Freedesktop.org notification specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/). This specification makes use of [D-Bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) for inter-process communication with a system wide notification implementation. On Linux and other Unix-like platforms this works pretty well. The requirements are D-Bus is running and there is an implementation of `org.freedesktop.Notifications`.

On Windows I'm not sure if D-Bus works. There might be a TCP implementation for Windows, but Unix sockets are used on Unix. If D-Bus can be run on Windows then there would also need to be an implementation of `org.freedesktop.Notifications` that translates the D-Bus messages to the Windows API for notifications. So it might be possible, but I can't find an implementation.

#### Update

As pointed out by @AlexB GIO's [GNotification](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Notification.html) provides cross platform system notifications. This includes [`org.freedesktop.Notifications`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gfdonotificationbackend.c), [Flatpak](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gportalnotificationbackend.c), [macOS](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gcocoanotificationbackend.m) and [Windows](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gwin32notificationbackend.c). Unfortunately at the current time the Windows implementation is [just a place holder](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/commit/b868cf5864e64cb2f6ea417053ea7bc4b83bc4a6). There is an [issue to fix this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/1234).

Comment: DBus works on Windows (via MSYS2) and it's theoretically possible to write a bridge between the Windows API and org.freedesktop.Notifications but if you want cross platform notifications use GNotification in GIO (GLib) it supports o.f.N, Flatpak, Windows and I think macOS

Comment: ty for answear. Can you give me an example? I haven't found GNotification in valadoc and tasting as here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723549/glib-notification-and-gnome-shell) I got the error.

gavr@archlabs ~> vala console.vala 
console.vala:4.24-4.35: error: The name `Notification' does not exist in the context of `GLib'.

Comment: @gavr you need to compile with `--pkg gio-2.0`

Comment: @AlThomas  https://pastebin.com/mw4mHMRj nothing happened 

g_application_send_notification: assertion 'G_IS_APPLICATION (application)' failed

Comment: @gavr, read my update then if you want to keep trying you need to use GApplication, so create `class MyApplication:Application {...}` that overrides a `startup` method and an empty `activate` method. e.g. https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Application.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987610/glib-graceful-termination-of-gapplication-on-unix-sigint/49987611#49987611